# Eliminar o último número que Digitei

Tags: python-3.x, while, append

Amigos, mais uma dúvida(^^). Observem o Código a seguir:

```
Numero = int(input('Digite um Numero'))

inteiro = []
inteiro.append(Numero)

while Numero>0:
  Numero = int(input('Digite um Numero'))
  inteiro.append(Numero)
if Numero<0:
  print(sorted(inteiro,reverse=True))
```

Na minha lista final, quero que imprima os valores anteriores ao último número.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema tem na verdade a ver com a forma como estruturou o programa. Dentro do `while` está a ler o numero e adiciona-o à lista independentemente do seu valor:

```
while Numero>0:
  Numero = int(input('Digite um Numero'))
  inteiro.append(Numero) # aqui adiciona mesmo se for 0 ou negativo
```

O número é adicionado mesmo quando não é valido, porque a comparação do `while` é feita depois. Para solucionar basta restruturar um pouco:

```
inteiro = []

while True:
  Numero = int(input('Digite um Numero'))
  if Numero <= 0: # logo após ler o numero vê se é inválido
      break # caso seja termina o while sem adicionar
  inteiro.append(Numero) # se for valido adiciona à lista e segue para o próximo

print(sorted(inteiro,reverse=True))
```

[Veja o código a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/a7wTmv)

Comment: Perfeito!!! Muito Obrigado^^